# How can I suggest things to W3C?

Tags: css, w3c

I have had a look on their website and cannot see anywhere to do it, does anyone know?

My proposal is that in addition to the 'inherit' and 'initial' keywords there should be a 'previous' keyword.

My reasoning is this:-

say my element has :-

```css
.myelement {
  background image: url(someimageurl), url(someotherimageurl);
}
```

maybe what I would like to do is override the second image on some occasions but not the other.

right now you have to do this

```css
.myelement.special {
  background image: url(someimageurl), url(someNEWotherimageurl);
}
```

The problem with this is that BOTH images on .myelement.special will stay the same no matter what .myelement is set to

but what if we want to let the previous option cascade through, there is no way of doing that I dont think

what we need is this:-

```css
.myelement.special {
  background image: previous, url(someNEWotherimageurl);
}
```

that way if .myelement is updated the first image still carries through to to the .myelement.special but the second image is overridden by .myelement.special's own style rule...

How can I propose this?

Comment: There are [mailing lists](http://www.w3.org/Mail/) where you can discuss about the specs: [www-style](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/), [css-discuss](http://www.css-discuss.org/), ... Not sure which is the proper one for your case